# What word starts with "pro", ends with "ive", and means generally-accepted or -expected

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

A front page article in USA Today this morning refers to Hillary Clinton as the "prohibitive Democratic front-runner."  I know that prohibitive is the wrong word here, but I can't remember the right one, which I am sure also starts with "pro" and ends with "ive", and means something like generally-accepted or generally-expected.  What's the word the writer was trying for here?

Comment: ***presumptive***?

Comment: Are you *sure* that "prohibitive" is not what the article intended?  Namely: As long as H.C. seems to be running, no on else will?

Comment: [Prohibitive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prohibitive) So likely to win as to discourage competition. Without getting too deep into politics, the word would work.

Comment: Perhaps it is an example of the reporter *misspeaking*. Oh dear!

Comment: Preeminent is what comes to mind, although that does not have the 'ive' ending.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is essentially a crossword puzzle clue.

Comment: How about "probably going to start a political fund raising drive"?

Answer (score 33):

Probably [prospective](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prospective):

> - Likely or expected to happen.
> - of or concerned with or related to the future; "prospective earnings,  "a prospective candidate.

- "prospective Democratic front-runner"

Comment: While prospective seems like a good, general fit, I think that presumptive is more appropriate given the political landscape in the US at the moment.

Comment: @Dancrumb my biggest problem with "prospective" is that "A" goes better (if not only) with it than the "THE" used by the original author (see quoted example: "A prospective candidate";see also the lack of any article at all in the answer). "Presumptive," on the other hand, although going well/only with "THE," would require changing "frontrunner" to "nominee." One either IS THE current, pre-nomination "frontrunner" or IS NOT, based on the current polls/contribution level/etc...no presumptions required/permitted.

Answer (score 30):

As Papa Poule wrote in [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226511/what-word-starts-with-pro-ends-with-ive-and-means-generally-accepted-or-e#comment484095_226511), *prohibitive* is exactly the right word:

> So likely to win as to discourage competition. [[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prohibitive)]

This is precisely what the reporter meant to say, and conveys the meaning exactly.

Comment: But that answer is non sequitur to a discussion of the English language.  "What did the reporter really mean?" could perhaps be an important philosophical question, but if the OP is searching for a word beginning with "pro", ending with "-ive", not "prohibitive" and meaning "generally accepted or generally expected" then your answer is flawed because it fails to address one of the criteria.

Comment: Answers to a flawed question that is obviously based on a false premise (i.e., "I KNOW that prohibitive is the WRONG word here") are no less flawed than the question itself if they don't address and challenge the false premise. @K.AlanBates OP wasn't looking for a synonym for "prohibitive," but was rather looking to correct a problem that didn't exist.

Comment: Plus one! Finally the ONE and ONLY correct answer to the OP's final, and in that sense ultimate, ENGLISH LANGUAGE/VOCABULARY question (What's the WORD the writer was trying for here?) Thank you! @K.AlanBates

Comment: Technically, it's not what the reporter meant to say, it's what David Axelrod's interviewer Susan Page meant to say, as the reporter is quoting her words.

Answer (score 22):

[Presumptive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presumptive):

1. based on probability or presumption
2. giving grounds for reasonable opinion or belief

---

Edit: just saw the comment [above](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226511/what-word-starts-with-pro-ends-with-ive-and-means-generally-accepted-or-e/226580#comment484089_226511).

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a program that scanned a dictionary with regular expressions.  The (exhaustive) list is:

- "proactive"
- "probative"
- "procreative"
- "productive"
- "prognosticative"
- "progressive"
- "prohibitive"
- "projective"
- "proliferative"
- "promotive"
- "propagative"
- "proprioceptive"
- "propulsive"
- "proscriptive"
- "prospective"
- "protective"
- "protensive"
- "protractive"
- "protrusive"
- "provocative"

I looked up the definitions of the ones I didn't know.  The only even remotely likely candidates are:

- "prognosticative" (a stretch, maybe)
- "progressive" (as in progressing to next)
- "**prospective**" (by far the most likely)
- "protensive" (maybe; would make more sense for an incumbent)
- "protractive" (a stretch, same as above)

Therefore, the best word is "prospective".

Comment: You can also use the filtering syntax at [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com) to achieve a similar result, by running a query on *`pro*ive`* and then selecting 'Filter by commonness' > 'Common words'. This generates the following list: 1. proactive 2. probative 
3. procreative 
4. productive 
5. progressive 
6. prohibitive 
7. projective 
8. promotive 
9. propagative 
10. proprioceptive 
11. propulsive 
12. prospective 
13. protective 
14. protrusive 
15. provocative; not quite as comprehensive a list as yours. For one that is at least as long you'd need to select 'All' instead of 'Common words'.

Comment: Haha! +1. A sure sign that this "English Language Q&A" web site has its roots in StackOverflow, a programmers' Q&A web site! :)

Comment: @augustin I started on stackoverflow so . . . confirmed! :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word you are seeking is **proscriptive**.

> proscribing or prohibiting, for example as according to a norm or standard

Comment: Proscriptive was the first word that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

pronormative; you generally won't find it in any but the THICKEST dictionaries. i.e. "old"

Comment: What does it mean?

Answer (score -1):

[Probative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probative):

1. serving to test or try :  exploratory
2. serving to prove :  substantiating